# How to use spreadsheets to organize object data at compile time in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, resources, organization

Using Visual Studio Community 2017 and C#.

I have for while now identified the need to have some better view of all the *initialization data* I have in my different class objects.

Today all the data are stored and initialized in the *constructors*. And if you have like 40 models of `car` classes and each class has its own properties of *speed, weight, engine power* and so on, you don't get such a good overview of the initialization data.

I am making a game with a lot of different objects  and I would like to have the data in spreadsheets and **I want that data to be imported/read to my objects at *compile time* not at *run time* since I don't want to distribute the data files with the application**.

I've been looking around, and searched to the end of my ability in finding the right keywords but...no. Maybe you can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use T4 templates to generate the configuration code for you from another source such as XML (or spreadsheets if need be)

You can add post build tasks to do this after each build or run the template manually when configuration changes.

A good sample can be found [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/jdothoffman/archive/2011/03/02/using-t4-to-generate-configuration-classes.aspx)

Comment: Ah! I think I get it. I'll consolidate all the data to be read from one (or some) classes and then _generate_ that code! The `code generation`could then be done via T4 or whatever between the project and the spreadsheets. Thanks!